# Is there a way to use windows authentication to connect to an sql server from xamarin?

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication, xamarin, windows-authentication

The mobile project i'm currently working on requires the user to sign in, and I want to use essentially what would be equivalent to including `Trusted_Connection=True;` in my connection string, since that way I could only have the user sign in once.

I've been looking around for a while now, and while i'm sure I can get the authentication part to work (using MSAL in combination with Xamarin.Essentials' Web Authenticator) I'm not quite sure how I would go about using the token I would retrieve to authenticate the connection. This is the code I'd be using if this was a desktop application:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=servername;Database=dbname;Trusted_connection=true;"))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblName", con);
    con.Open();
    //Do something here
    con.Close();
}
```

I should also add that using the `Authentication` keyword, which I read about [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15), doesn't work for me since it crashes with this error message:

`System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'authentication'.'`

Security is not a concern as you have to connect to the company WiFi to connect to the SQL Server.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: On what device ? if it's mobile then - not really ... moreover, if it's mobile,  then you should not use direct connection to SQL anyway

Comment: Then you should be connecting to an API, and then that should be connecting to your instance.

Comment: Do some WebAPI, do OAUTH2 auth and that's it ... you are not really logged to windows domain on android device so there is no "Trusted Connection"

Comment: This would have to run on phones, yes- what would be the way to go about it then? I've read that people use APIs and such, but I'm not familiar with that at all...

Comment: Actually [there is a way to use Windows Authentication through Kerberos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/enable-kerberos?view=sql-server-ver15). It requires a bit of work to set up client and server, and requires manually retrieving a Kerberos token. What OS are you running on? You can join a Mac to a Windows Active Directory domain

Comment: @Chris `This would have to run on phones` how will you even connect to the database then? You have a much bigger problem than using Windows Authentication.

Comment: @Selvin not in the original question. And if it's Android, it makes no sense at all trying to connect to a server directly. Even for WiFi connections to an on-prem server. Databases are chatty and want stable connections

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm running the newest version of windows, but I can't tell you what Android versions the phones will run on since it's gonna be running on more than one - but i'd assume rather old versions.

Comment: @Chris the point is that you shouldn't be connecting to the database directly in the first place. Databases require stable connections and even WiFi phone connections are anything but. Mobile connections - don't even think about it. The **ONLY** guarantee in a mobile application is that the server connection will fail

Comment: moreover, directly connecting to your SQL Server from a mobile client requires that your SQL Server be exposed on the web.  This is a good way to guarantee that your server gets hacked and your data is stolen.

Comment: @Jason The only way to connect to the sql server from outside of the company I'm working for is to use a vpn, which you need 2fa for, or to be in the company directly. Despite that, we're not planning to let anyone use a vpn on their phone anyway, so as long as the company wifi is secure, this is not an issue.

Comment: Those are all important factors that you should probably include in the body of your question.  I have done Xamarin apps that do direct db access in scenarios where the app was only used on-premise over secure WiFi.